# How to transfer folder from Mega.nz to GDrive?

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, rclone

I have access to unlimited GDrive suite and I would like to transfer a public folder from Mega to my Drive. Here are the steps I have already tried along with their issues I faced :

1. [Google Colab method](https://github.com/cheems/Mega-to-Google-Drive/blob/master/Transfer_files_from_Mega_to_Google_Drive.ipynb) --> Colab disconnecting after 5-10 minutes of running; Issue already raised on Github code
2. [MultiCloud](https://www.multcloud.com) --> Possible to copy files in my MegaDrive; but I want to copy public folders such as [this one](https://mega.nz/folder/xpwGQRpA#V9HcMxVmSBWH1X-FCDopLQ)
3. [RClone](https://rclone.org/mega/) --> Same issue as above; Also an error generated while creating a config file
4. [Mega.py library](https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/) --> Only for files, not folders; [Error](https://ibb.co/YbQyhBC) when downloading from mega.nz as documentation mentions only for mega.co.nz
5. [MegaCopy from MegaTools](https://megatools.megous.com) --> Did not find a Windows implementation; also need a python integration of it if possible
6. The old, download from Mega and upload to Google Drive method --> Extremely slow download speed

I am exhausted and out of ideas I can think of for this seemingly easy task. It would be extremely helpful if someone could be of my help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely go with Google Colab.
You just have to install MegaCMD in your Notebook, mount your google drive and get your folder(s)!
I just created one for this purpose: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tadBcXE4vkKaFETsWGJ_B7O8uKxp6E9J?usp=sharing

Edit: the content of the Notebook:

1. Import GDrive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2. Move to your mounted drive and create directory:

```
cd /content/drive/MyDrive/
!mkdir MegaImport
cd MegaImport
```

3. Install dependencies:

```
!apt install libmms0 libc-ares2 libc6 libcrypto++6 libgcc1 libmediainfo0v5 libpcre3 libpcrecpp0v5 libssl1.1 libstdc++6 libzen0v5 zlib1g apt-transport-https
```

4. Download and install MegaCMD:

```
!wget https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_9.0/amd64/megacmd_1.4.0-3.1_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i megacmd_1.4.0-3.1_amd64.deb
```

5. Login to Mega (replace with your email and pwd):

```
!mega-login email password
```

6. Get the folder you wish:

```
!mega-get <remote_folder> ./
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stand up a free tier AWS EC2 instance, or use GCE's new account credit, to run a virtual computer in the cloud for free or mostly free. You could then download and upload from that machine. That would sidestep the download speed issues you're having.